# Remove "." from inside CSV files in Row

Tags: python, csv

I want to do this:

```
fundos_btg_2017= pd.merge(fundo_completo_2017,index_fundos_btg, on="CNPJ_FUNDO",how="inner")
```

But `"CNPJ_FUNDO"` in one file is in the `format= 214709890001-77` and the `other= 00.017.024/0001-53` 
I want to remove the dots and the `"/"` in the second file or add in the first.
I am a true beginner in python and need help, this may be really easy but I don't know how to do.
I know I can do it in excel pretty fast but I want to automatize the process. 
Thank you for your Time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second df remove the `.` and `/`

```
index_fundos_btg['CNPJ_FUNDO'] = index_fundos_btg['CNPJ_FUNDO'].replace(r'\.|/', '', regex=True)
```

Then merge

```
fundos_btg_2017= pd.merge(fundo_completo_2017, index_fundos_btg, on="CNPJ_FUNDO",how="inner")
```

Comment: since you're here I will ask you another question. I had to create a csv file with the information in columns(x,y,z). Now I have to change the csv file in the following order : column (x)   column(x2)                                                                                                                           line(y)    value (z)      value(z2)                                                                                         line(y2)  value(z3- that was in the same line before with x and y2)

Comment: order : column (x)   column(x2)                                                                                                                           line(y)    value (z)      value(z2)                                                                                         line(y2)  value(z3- that was in the same line before with x and y2)